# How to use Inner Join along with Where in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 separate tables which are ***tuition*** and ***user***. In the *tuition* table I have 2 fields named `user_id` and `admin_id`. I access related users by using `Inner Join` clause and `user_id`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tuition t JOIN user u ON t.user_id = u.id
```

But in the *tuition* table, I want join only records in *tuition* which their `admin_id` is equal to `1`. How should I rewrite the clause above? I wrote as this but didn't show me anything:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tuition t JOIN user u ON t.user_id = u.id WHERE admin_id=1
SELECT * FROM tuition t WHERE admin_id=1 AND JOIN user u ON t.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: What does "*but didn't work*" mean? Did you get error or did you get the wrong output? Consider updating your post with full details to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including sample input data, current output, expected output and the error if any error is thrown.

Comment: My sentence is obvious. It didn't show me the result I wanted.

Comment: If we dont know what teh result should be, how can we help with the query ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where clause with inner join queries should be referenced with table name.

```
SELECT * FROM tuition t JOIN user u ON t.user_id = u.id WHERE table_name.admin_id=1
```